# Is masking an entered password security through obscurity?

Tags: security

There is a practice of showing bullets, not characters when a user inputs a password. Is this security through obscurity?

My first thought was that it's not, it's not really a system, we know how it works, one bullet = one character. It's just not showing the password so I don't think the definition of security by obscurity applies here. However, I'm not sure about it.

Comment: Some systems output a random number of bullets/asterisks (within a short range of course) for each entered character to make it harder for over-lookers to spot the number of characters in the entered password. I don't encounter this anymore, for some reason it got out of style, yet it struck me as a smart thing to do.

Comment: @MartinMaat I was just thinking alike. Then I thought of my mother and almost immediately I have realised that It could be seen as a misleading and confusing feature. Imagine a layman typing down 10 characters password but only half are printed. Cognitively it is disturbing.

Comment: Someone could look on your fingers and keyboard...

Comment: On [security.se]: [Why do password creation/login screens hide the typed password?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/124890/why-do-password-creation-login-screens-hide-the-typed-password)

Comment: @Laiv I have never seen this with nothing appearing in response to a key stroke, it was always multiple placeholders per character. And my mother does not need any of this to be confused by her computer.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with security through obscurity - as long as it isn’t the only security. I know one really big attack target where the “obscurity” stopped attackers for several years.

Comment: Example: hiding services by changing the standard port address to something different is considered good practice among network administrators... yet, totally security through obscurity!

Comment: @MartinMaat because it cuts down amount of everyday attacks performed by bots by 99.9+%. You have to _specifically_ target some system to use port scanning.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Apparently you can simply record the sound of someone typing and use statistical analysis to determine their password.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Rather than the hand-waving "security via obscurity", I think you're best taking [Kerckhoff's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle):

> a cryptosystem should be secure, even if everything about the system, except the key, is public knowledge.

where the password is the "key" in this case. Security via obscurity is anything where the security of the system depends on something other than the key being kept secret.

As such, hiding the characters of the password as its is entered is absolutely not security via obscurity as it is **protecting the one bit of the system which must be protected** for it *not* to be security via obscurity. It is designed to protect against one very specific attack vector (shoulder surfers), and does that well.

Comment: I would say it protects *somewhat*, rather than *very well*. Reading a password from keypresses is harder than from a dialog box, but at the speed that most people use for typing noise strings it is perfectly feasible.

Comment: @KilianFoth I didn't say it protects "very well", I said it was a very specific attack vector.

Comment: The bullets are not a secret of how the system works. They are part of how the key is kept secret. An opponent knowing that the system uses bullets doesn’t weaken the systems security.